# Focuswriter on ubuntu 16.04 using source code.

Tags: 16.04, hunspell

I am trying to install focuswriter on ubuntu 16.04 using source code. So after opeing terminal in the focuswriter folder I enter qmake but then this error appears - 'Project ERROR - Package hunspell not found'. I already have hunspell installed.

Comment: Maybe you are after `libhunspell-dev`? Perhaps give a bit more detail into your compiling process: the steps you have already undertaken...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have `hunspell` installed which gives applications the ability to use it, but you may not have `libhunspell-dev` which provides the source code needed to compile programs that use it.

You may be able to get all the packages you need using:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep focuswriter
```

Then you can proceed to recompile.

Comment: Thank you very much libhunspell-dev was what I was missing